# Fastest Way To Lookup Dictionary Item Meeting 2 Separate Criteria

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 3 elements:  URL, Speed, Online.

```
URL = text string (using it as the key)
Speed = integer
Online = True/False
```

I need to get the key of the dictionary item with the lowest Speed integer where Online = True.

Speed is extremely important for this look up in the script.

What's the fastest way to get the key?

A loop is they way I'm doing to currently.  Is there something faster?

```
dict = {'url1.com': [1, False],  'url2.com': [5, True],
              'url3.net': [2, False], 'url4.org': [3, True],
              'url5.net': [2, True]}

min = 99999
for key, first in dict.items():
    online = first[1]
    if online == True:
        speed = first[0]
        print speed

        if speed < min:
            current_key = key
            min = speed

print current_key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to optimize for speed you need to use something other than a dict to store the data.  As you calculate the values for "speed" you could retain the lowest value in a variable to be used at the end.  Then you don't have to go through every item in the dict again to figure out which is the lowest value.

Answer (score 3):

```
print min((x for x in data_dict.items() if x[-1][-1]),key=lambda x:x[-1])
```

is one way you could do this, this uses a generator for the filter step to avoid looping twice

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can't get away from the fact that you have to walk through all the key-value pairs checking.   I couldn't think of a way to use a generator to replace the for.

You had some extraneous assignments and things though.

```
min = 99999
for key, first in dict.items():
    if first[1]:
        if first[0] < min:
            min = first[0]
            current_key = key

print current_key
```

Comment: Thanks.  This one tested out the fastest so far.

Comment: you should probably time the solutions using much larger datasets than the example in the Original question ... you may find interesting things when using larger datasets

Comment: actually it looks like this is pretty fast even with much larger datasets (+1)

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (x,y): y[0], reverse=True): # for py3.x do list(d.items())
    if all(v):
        print k
        break
```